# How to run parallel processes in Java EE

Tags: java, multithreading, jsf, jakarta-ee

In my test application (JSF, PrimeFaces, Wildfly 8) I have a simple messaging interface for writing a message and viewing those that were sent to me. I now would like to create an automatic respond for those messages that were not answered after 5 minutes. This automatic respond is meant to be independent of any person sitting behind the browser window and clicking the refresh button.

My current idea is to create a new class annotated with @ApplicationScoped. This class shall run an individual thread handling the responding process. Would that be a good approach? Or is there a functionality somewhere that already covers this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the option worth considering would be to use javax.ejb.TimerService:

```
@Stateless
public class AutomaticResponseSender {

    private static final Integer _5_MINS = 300000;

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    public void waitFiveMinutes() {
        Timer nextTimer = timerService.createSingleActionTimer(_5_MINS, null);
    }

    @Timeout
    public void autoRespondForNotAnswered() {
          // here send an auto response
    }

    public void cancel() {
        timerService.cancel();
    }
}
```

Upon sending the manual answer you need to call `cancel()` to avoid autoresponse or, alternatively, you can check in `autoRespondForNotAnswered()` method if the answer was send.

Another approach could be to use [@Schedule](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) and, let's say every 5 or 10 seconds, check for messages not answered in 5 mins and sending automatic answers for them.